# eclipselink manytoone not save

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

i have a persit problem with elcipselink

here is my model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_ASSOC_LANGUE_CODE_BE_GARE")
public class AssocLangueCodeBeGare {

@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id_langue", column = @Column(name = "ID_LANGUE") ),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id_gare", column = @Column(name = "ID_GARE") ) })
@EmbeddedId
private AssocLangueCodeBeGareFK key;

@Column(name = "CODE_BE", length = 4)
private String codeBe;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "ID_GARE", referencedColumnName = "ID_GARE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private StopPoint stopPoint;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_LANGUE", referencedColumnName = "ID_LANGUE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Langue langue;
```

in StopPoint i don t reference table AssocLangueCodeBeGare, i don t need it.

then when i do :

```
this.serviceStopPoint.save(currentStopPoint);
            for (AssocLangueCodeBeGare assoc : listAssocLangueCodeBeGare) {
                assoc.setStopPoint(currentStopPoint);
                this.serviceAssocLangueCodeBeGare.save(assoc);
            }
```

save is

```
@Override
public void save(T entityToSave) {
    this.getEntityManager().persist(entityToSave);
}
```

I m using batch insert for writing and sometimes when i save another entity flush is done and i get  :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: NULL not allowed for column "ID_GARE"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO TBL_ASSOC_LANGUE_CODE_BE_GARE (CODE_BE, ID_GARE, ID_LANGUE) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [23502-192]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.executeBatch(DatabasePlatform.java:2134)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeJDK12BatchStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:871)
```

does i miss something in the mapping?

does i need to add something like this in stoppoint entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "stopPoint", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<AssocLangueCodeBeGare> assocLangueCodeBeGares;
```

@EDIT1

I think its caused by my EmbeddedId because it was null!! the mapping does'nt set correct value in the embedable object?

here is the embedable object :

```
@Embeddable
public class AssocLangueCodeBeGareFK implements Serializable {

private String id_langue;
private Long id_gare;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: The insertable = false and updatable = false prevent the value from the mapping from being written to the database.  Hopefully you have another mapping to that database column and are setting the value, or it won't get set.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i  find a solution :

I use `@IdClass(AssocLangueCodeBeGareFK.class` on AssocLangueCodeBeGare

And i put @id on

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "ID_GARE", referencedColumnName = "ID_GARE")
private StopPoint stopPoint;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_LANGUE", referencedColumnName = "ID_LANGUE")
private Langue langue;
```

I rename on my AssocLangueCodeBeGareFK class name of my property to be the same as the AssocLangueCodeBeGare class :

```
 private Long stopPoint;
 private String langue;
```

now all work like a charm.

if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

The insertable = false and updatable = false prevent the value from the mapping from being written to the database.  You need to have another mapping to that database column with the value set, or it won't get into the database.  While making your OneToMany the ID works, so would the MapsId annotation in the current code as JPA will then set the value in your embeddable ID.  Or you could have manually added the value from the referenced class into the appropriate AssocLangueCodeBeGare.key fields.

Comment: yes, thats why i have use @idclass to keep my composite key and all work fine now.

Comment: I am surprised you are not getting an error or warnings when deploying the persistence unit, as your answer shows insertable=false, which prevents the ID fields from being inserted with a value.  My answer was attempting to explain your issue was not in your original approach, but in your use of insertable=false on the mapping you wanted to use to control the database field.

Comment: sorry, you are right ;) it s a bad copy/paste :( i remove them in my answer ;)